# N-Grams using Map Reduce and MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, mapreduce, nlp, n-gram

I'm interested in adding a new collection to an existing db in MongoDB based on an existing collection's (let's call it X) sentences. The new collection should contain the X collection N-Grams (N=2 and N=3 for now actually).

I have a working function that creates BOW using Map Reduce and save it on MongoDB but my knowledge with Map Reduce is limited so don't really know what needs to be changed for using it for N-Grams.

The existing BOW Map Reduce function I have is (I'm attaching it because I believe there's a small change need to be made):

```
db = MongoClient().bow
db_entities = MongoDocFetcher(p_name, collection)

sentences = []
for idx, doc in enumerate(db_entities):
    sentences.append({})
    sentences[idx]["tags"] = doc[DBKeys.processed_words]

result = db.things.insert_many(sentences)

result.inserted_ids

pipeline = [
    {"$unwind": "$tags"},
    {"$group": {"_id": "$tags", "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
    {"$sort": SON([("count", -1), ("_id", -1)])}
]

list(db.things.aggregate(pipeline))
db.command('aggregate', 'things', pipeline=pipeline, explain=True)

mapper = Code("""
              function () {
              this.tags.forEach(function(z) {
              emit(z, 1);
              });
              }
              """)

reducer = Code("""
               function (key, values) {
               var total = 0;
               for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
               total += values[i];
               }
               return total;
               }
               """)

db.things.map_reduce(mapper, reducer, p_name)
db.things.drop()
```